# query string format input UserId and password

Tags: asp.net-web-api, angular7

I need a this format Url:

```
http://localhost:8089/api/Logins/CheckPassword?ID=[UserID]&Password=[Password]
```

My code does not work:

**loginComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { LoginService } from '../login.service';
import { Login } from '../login';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
loginForm: FormGroup;
loading=false;
submitted=false;
url: string;
   constructor(
     private formbuilder: FormBuilder, 
     private loginService: LoginService,
     private router:Router,
     private route: ActivatedRoute
      ) {
        if(this.loginService.getLoginById)
        {
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
        }
       }
   ngOnInit() {
      this.loginForm = this.formbuilder.group({
        Id: ['', [Validators.required]],
        password: ['',Validators.required]
    });
   }
  get f()
  {
    return this.loginForm.controls;
  }
   onFormSubmit() {
  this.submitted=true;
  if(this.loginForm.invalid)
  {
    return;
  }
  this.loading=true;
  this.loginService.getLoginById()
  //.pipe(first())
  .subscribe(
    data =>{
      this.router.navigate([this.url]);
    },
    error =>
    {
      this.loading=false;
    });
    }
}
```

**loginService.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Login } from './login';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
       getLoginById(): Observable<any>{
        const _params=new HttpParams();
    _params: _params.set('ID=','UserID');
    _params: _params.set('Password=','Password');
    return 
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8089/api/Logins/CheckPassword?', 
   {
      params:_params
    });
    console.log(_params);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please pay attention to the format, especially the code block! Also, what do you mean by "I need a this format Url:"? What's not working with your code?

Comment: Do you have any sample code please send to me, not getting proper format. I have login page user enter the Id and password should go http://localhost:8089/api/Logins/CheckPassword?ID=[raju]&Password=[test123]

Comment: Sorry I don't have any sample and I am not familiar with asp.net or angular7. However, my questions in the comment is generic. You need to clarify what your goal is and what specific error you get with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here 'UserID' and 'password' should be replaced with the actual value.I do not see it in your code where you are getting these values.you need to call a method to populate your Userid and password

```
 const _params=new HttpParams();
        _params: _params.set('ID=','raju'); 
        _params: _params.set('Password=','password123');
        return 
        this.http.get('http://localhost:8089/api/Logins/CheckPassword?', 
       {
          params:_params

      });
```

Comment: Hi Ashok, thanks for your response. do you have any sample code, if you have can you please send to me it will help lot for me.